# How can I get values from address of Place Picker?

Tags: android, google-places

I want to get values from address of Place Picker in android and separate it into different EditText like I want to set pincode on `PineCodeEditText`, set country on `CountryEditText`, set State on `StateEditText` and so on. I have got address as

> 10, Mothorowala Rd, Jagdamba Colony, Dharmpur, Ajabpur Kalan,
>   Dehradun, Uttarakhand 248001, India

Where I used

> Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data,this);
>
> String address = String.format(String.valueOf(place.getAddress()));

Before this I used Split function but it gives `indexOutOfBoundException`. 
Any suggestion please welcome, Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the latitude and longitude coordinates from the `Place` object, then get the address object using the `GeoCoder`, which you can use to get the required data separately.

```
LatLng coordinates = place.getLatLng(); // Get the coordinates from your place
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                            coordinates.latitude,
                            coordinates.longitude,
                            1); // Only retrieve 1 address
Address address = addresses.get(0);
String countryCode = address.getCountryCode();
String countryName = address.getCountryName();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply @Nader, I have done this before your post